# WPF&MVVM: Обобщённая конструкция gettter-а и setter-а во ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Изучаю паттерн MVVM для WPF. В примере ниже мне непонятна конструкция getter-ов и setter-ов.

```
namespace MVVM_Tutorial {

    public class Phone : INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private string title;
        private string company;
        private int price;

        public string Title {
            get { return title; }
            set {
                title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }

        public string Company {
            get { return company; }
            set {
                company = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Company");
            }
        }
    //...
    }
}
```

Что именно непонятно:

- Что такое Title и Company (как единица кода, естественно) и почему они пишyтся с большой буквы? Вероятно, это сокращённая запись взамен декларирования getter-а и setter-а в виде двух отдельных функций? В этом случае, установлено правило, что такая конструкция должна называться так же, как и поле класса, только с большой буквы?
- Я понял, что в строке `title = value;` мы присваиваем новое значение, но что есть value как единица кода? У меня она подсвечивается как ключевое слово, стало быть, значение данной единицы определено в классе `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

На всякий случай приведу ссылкн на источник [урока](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.2.php), по которому я изучаю wpf и данный паттерн.

Заранее благодарю Всех за ответы.

Comment: Title и Company - свойства. С большой буквы такой стиль. Да, это сахар вместо getTitle()/setTitle(). Называться может как угодно, никаких обязательств нет. value - неявное значение сеттера - эквивалент setTitle(value)

Comment: @vitidev, благодарю Вас за объяснение!